# mysql configuration error on windows vista

Tags: mysql, configuration, windows-vista

I am trying to install and configure MySQL 5.0.41 on Windows Vista Home Premium and am getting the following error message:

Could not connect to the Service Control Manager. Error: 0

I am running the installer via an Administrator account, so I'm not sure why it would not have access to this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.  Even when running the configuration application as an Administrator, you must have the "User Access Control" setting in Vista disabled. (And restart the machine after disabling it.)